# create a new column that arrange data frame order based on previous columns

Tags: r

i have a data frame like this:

```
  A     B      C    
1   1   1 0.4519
2 101   1 0.3819
3 201   1 0.3819
4 301   1 0.2819
5 401   1 0.9819
6 501   1 0.6819
```

it's larger but that's an example.

i want to create a new column called `order` which include a number from `(1 until nrow(df))` and it increase based on the value of the `C` column (1 for smallest value and increase with increasing `C` value). and when the values in column C are equal change the ordering criteria to column `A` and when the values in column A are equal, change it to column `B`.

is this can be done in R in an easy and efficient way?

this can be done using a for loop on the data frame and make some if statement, but it will take to much time to finish. that's why i need a faster alternative if possible

thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can use `order` to sort data based on several columns. According to `order` documentation:

> In the case of ties in the first vector, values in the second are
>     used to break the ties.  If the values are still tied, values in
>     the later arguments are used to break the tie.

This would be your sample data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(list(A=c(1, 101, 201, 301, 401, 501),
                      B=rep(1, 6),
                      C=c(0.45, 0.38, 0.38, 0.28, 0.98, 0.68)))
```

And this is the code that creates a new column in the data frame based on the order you want:

```
df$order <- order(df$C, df$A, df$B)
```

Comment: this is not giving correct answers, i made some changes to the column B (it does not contain equal values anymore) but the values of the order are not correct ..

Comment: can you add a small example where it fails?

Comment: i used `rank` instead and it worked like a charm using `ties.method="first"` ..

in your example it works perfectly, but i don't know why it did not worked on my bigger dataframe(eventhought it should work because it's the same data). but rank sloved my problem.